# tabView that occupies half of screen

Tags: swift, tabbar

Like you see in the picture below, I added a tabBar in the middle of the screen and I would like it to switch between two views just in the bottom part of the screen. Is there anyway to accomplish that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can accomplish this using containerViews , drag a VC from the object library and drag 2 UIContainerViews inside it hooked to the top & bottom anchros respectively with equal-height constraint between them , then embed each child VC inside a UITaBarController , aslo you can accomplish this programmatically by adding the 2 child UITabBarControllers to the mainVC with appropriate constraints to make them occupy the required space

Comment: ty a lot guys, that was to great help -don't know at the . moment  (new to swift)  whos answer is more correct so I took so sorry in case of misstake of accepting incorrecly, ty again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use another VC on top of the one you already have, I can't tell you exactly how to do it but I was able to create a very similar effect to what you want using this repo: https://github.com/martinnormark/HalfModalPresentationController
This uses another VC for the bottom half view of the screen and while its present, you can't interact with the top half (in your case, your calendar).

Alternatively, if you don't want to use another View Controller but rather a simple UIView inside the VC you already have, you can use this code to detect when a button on the TabBar is selected.

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.title = "some_title" {
        firstView.isHidden = true
        secondView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `UITabBarDelegate` to your class and to link the TabBar to the delegate on the interface builder (or add `tabBar.delegate = self` on your viewDidLoad).